# Redirect 301 in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I worked with Spree and I found this line in while doing 'rake routes'

```
api GET|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE /api/v:api/*path(.:format)      redirect(301) {:format=>"json"}
    GET|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE /api/*path(.:format)            redirect(301) {:format=>"json"}
```

What does it mean?
what is v:api and what is redirect(301)?
I know what redirect(301) is but what will be the new route?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on the latest version of Spree, that route is likely generated by this code: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/f68afc19515b78d151c2663927678901954ea435/api/config/routes.rb#L171-L191

Based on that code it looks like some kind of redirect for legacy `api/v1` requests. If I'm reading that code correctly, it seems Spree wants to override some of those routes in order to redirect to the `v1` namespace. The 301 is just the status for the redirect and it forwards the request as JSON

Comment: Hi Pennypacker. Thanks for your message.
 I am using Spree Version 3.7.2
And it doesn't show 404 Error.
And what is exactly this statement doing? 
 redirect(301) {:format=>"json"}